# How do I insert a snippet of text using a keyboard shortcut in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How do I set a shortcut for inserting `console.log()` and wrapping it around my current selection in Sublime Text without installing any plugin or extra third-party stuff?

Comment: The question itself (without the answer) isn't quite clear on what you mean. If you rephrase to something asking about how to insert a snippet of text (with console.log() as an example) using a keyboard shortcut in Sublime Text it might be more useful to everyone. =)

Comment: I've given a crack at editing as well. If you feel this wasn't an improvement, feel free to change it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I found the answer. Thought I'd add it here for others:

Go to `Sublime Text 2 > Preferences > Key Bindings - User` and add this JSON to the file:

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+d"],
      "command": "insert_snippet",
      "args": {
        "contents": "console.log(${1:}$SELECTION);${0}"
      }
    }
]
```

Inserts a `console.log()` at the current cursor position on pressing `alt+d`.

Reference: https://gist.github.com/harthur/2951063